# symfony2 phpunit : how to drop and copy database before running tests?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, testing, phpunit

In my symfony2 application, I am using phpunit to verify that the response from every route has a code 200.

Before I run the tests, I want to drop the test database and copy my production database under the name test (i.e. I want to reinitiate my test database).

I learned about the `public static function setUpBeforeClass()` but I am lost as to how drop and copy the database.

How can I do that ?

My class so far :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Tests\Controller;

use AppBundle\FoodMeUpParameters;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

require_once __DIR__.'/../../../../app/AppKernel.php';


class ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest extends WebTestCase
{

    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider routeProvider
     * @param $route
     */
    public function testAllRoutesAreLoaded($route)
    {
        $listedRoutes = $this->getListedRoutes();

        $this->assertArrayHasKey($route, $listedRoutes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out Doctrine's Data Fixtures

Comment: yep, I know a bit about fixtures and I am using this but I don't see how I can drop an entire database here...

Comment: When you load the Data Fixtures, there is the option to truncate your entire database and then load the new data in.

Comment: well, the $executor->execute($loader->getFixtures(), false); will empty the database but not drop it, am I right ? then I want to copy another existing database under the name test.

Comment: oh okay you want to copy the data from the existing database? that's not how fixtures works, but that's fine. The easiest way would be to use mysql dump on the old db, and then mysql import with that .sql file.

Answer (score 1):

This is some PHP code to back up a MySQL DB. The --routines includes your views, functions, stored proc, etc.

```
<?php
$schemaFile = "schema.sql";
$mysqlArgs  = "-u {$dbUser} -h {$dbHost} {$dbName}";

//if you don't have a pass and still pass in arg -p it will interrupt and prompt
if (isset($dbPassword) && strlen(trim($dbPassword)) > 0) { 
    $mysqlArgs .= " -p{$dbPassword}";
}

$mysqlDumpCommand = "mysqldump {$mysqlArgs} --routines";
$schemaDump       = "{$mysqlDumpCommand} > {$schemaFile}";
system($schemaDump);
```

Then the code to import it assuming same `$mysqlArgs` code as above.

```
$mysqlImportCommand = "mysql {$mysqlArgs}";
$import             = "{$mysqlImportCommand} < {$schemaFile}";
system($import);
```

Answer (score 1):

My 5c. Usually you don't need to use `setUpBeforeClass` because it will populate DB for the whole suite and therefore create a risk of test dependency while unit tests must be independent. Use `setUp` and `tearDown` methods instead. Now to the point: you said you just want to test that response is code 200. Why would you want to populate the whole DB for that in the first place when you can simply mock expected responses from your models?

Comment: well, it's much faster to test that every route gets a response 200 than defining the expected answer for all models. that's a first basic check

Comment: No it's not since there's a huge overhead on DB operations. Also imagine that one of the routes you are testing, updates DB. How you can be sure that following tests doesn't give you false positive?

Comment: Well, I know what I'm doing and routes are ordered in away bad things won't happen. I could do something perfect but here I want to do something fast and just ok. Making it perfect requires more time and I'm working on it, little by little